# can't copy object properties to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, copying

this should be simple enough, but i'm having trouble copying the properties of an object to another.

```
var tableFormatting = {
    table: {
        style: {
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px"
        },
        border: "1px"
    }
    //similar code for tbody, tr, td  
};
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var p in tableFormatting.table)
table[p] = tableFormatting.table[p];
alert(table.style.width); //shows nothing. can't access it  
alert(typeof(table.style.width)); //shows string, so i know it was copied or has a reference
alert(table.border); //shows 1px. this one is copied and accessible
```

why aren't the style properties displaying?

Comment: @sємsєм, what language are you programming in? foreach is not in JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello Oh! sorry! I've got confused.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deep copy them

```
function copyValues( dst, src ) {
    for( var key in src ) {
        var value = src[key];
        if( typeof value == "object" ) {
            copyValues( dst[key], value );
        }
        else {
            dst[key] = value;
        }
    }
}

copyValues( table, tableFormatting.table );
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/RpJKH/

Otherwise, what's happening is the manual equivalent of:

```
 table.style = obj.style
```

And of course that does nothing, because `.style` is read-only.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, you might want to consider adding `value instanceof Array` check in there as well as `src.hasOwnProperty(p)`. `typeof someArray` returns `object`, too, in which case `someArray.slice(0);` works just fine (provided its an array of primitives)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem what properties of dom elements are represented as arrays? I guess ClassList, but that's covered by `.className`

Comment: @Esailija: I just added the comment for completeness, in case somebody would use this code to set multiple classes: `{className: ['foo', 'bar']}`, or use it to actually copy any object literal

Comment: thank you my friend!! i was afraid i was going to have to deep copy.  is table.style = obj.style read-only so that table isn't able to modify obj.style?